# Como crear id únicos de sincronización laravel mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, asincronismo

Tengo un servidor con laravel y el paquete laravel passport. A este servidor se conectan varios clientes. Los clientes descargan json del server y lo guardan en base de datos local. A su vez también producen datos que los sincronizan al server al retornar la conexión de internet.
Mi problema radica en los id de las tablas. Ej: tabla sales id=x. Cuando lo sincronizo es posible que ya exista el id=x, creado por otro cliente.
¿Existe alguna forma convencional de resolver esto?.
Lo único que se me ocurre es un timestamp+id_usuario. Pero nose si seria una opción adecuada en términos de rendimiento.
Soy programador aficionado, y estoy trabajando con sincronizacion clientes-servidor por primera vez, probablemente estoy teniendo un enfoque erroneo al indexar las tablas y seleccionar id primario.
Cualquier recomendación y lectura que ayude a abstraer y entender los conceptos de sincronizacion sera bienvenida.

Comment: puedes usar id randoms mas complejas como las de mongoDB es muy dificil que se repita una asi (1/16.777.216 si se generan todas en el mismo segundo, osea super imposible), pero tambien estaria bueno timestamp+id_usuario+id_x

Comment: `uniqid` es un generador de `id` con una cadena aleatoria de caracters

Comment: Gracias. voy a probar con uniqid. El tema es que tanto baja el rendimiento al usarlo como clave primaria en una tabla donde se van sumando unos 50mil registros nuevos cada mes